# Remote form with paperclip in Rails?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a Rails app and trying to make a remote form, so far it is not really working out.. can someone point me to what I am doing wrong here:

So models:

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :galaxy, :title, :rss_url, :avatar
  has_many :stories
  has_many :plots, :through => :stories




class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :galaxy, :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :content
  belongs_to :media
  has_many :plots




class Plot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plotable, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :plots, :as => :plotable
  has_many :soundtracks, :as => :soundtrackable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :soundtracks, :allow_destroy => true
```

So view in app/views/medias/show.html.erb::

```
  <% @media.stories.each do |s| %>
   <%= form_for :plot, :remote => true, :html => { :id => 'pl_form' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :soundtracks do |soundtrack_fields| %> 
       <%= soundtrack_fields.file_field :soundtrack %>
     <% end %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, s.content, :style =>"display:none" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
```

app/views/plots/create.js.erb

```
var el = $('#new_pl');
  // We could also render a partial to display the plot here
  $('#plots').append("<%= escape_javascript( 
      simple_format( @plot.body ) 
    ) %>");
  el.find('input:text,textarea').val('');
  el.find('.errors').empty();
<% end %>
```

Controllers are standard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add multipart true to your form

```
 <%= form_for :plot, :remote => true, :html => { :id => 'pl_form', :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

[Multipart](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) from W3C

> The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data